Remove javax.annotation.Generated from generated Open API files
I cannot remove javax.annotation.Generated from generated API classes in SpringBoot3 application, using Maven OpenAPI generator plugin. This is what I have from dependencies:
 <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
                            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/com/sample/test.yaml</inputSpec>
                            <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                            <apiPackage>my.controller</apiPackage>
                            <modelPackage>my.model</modelPackage>
                            <generateSupportingFiles>true</generateSupportingFiles>
                            <configOptions>
                                <useJakartaEe>true</useJakartaEe>
                                <library>spring-boot</library>
                                <useSpringController>true</useSpringController>
                                <!-- javax.* to jakarta.* -->
                                <useSpringfox>false</useSpringfox>
                                <useSpringBoot3>true</useSpringBoot3>
                                <oas3>true</oas3>
                                <useTags>true</useTags>
                                <interfaceOnly>false</interfaceOnly>
                                <enableBuilderSupport>true</enableBuilderSupport>
                                <collectionFluentPattern>true</collectionFluentPattern>
                                <openApiNullable>false</openApiNullable>
                                <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                                <serializableModel>true</serializableModel>
                                <delegatePattern>true</delegatePattern>
                                <useBeanValidation>true</useBeanValidation>
                                <hideGenerationTimestamp>true</hideGenerationTimestamp>
                                <simpleFluentPattern>true</simpleFluentPattern>
                                <unhandledException>true</unhandledException>
                            </configOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

In dependencies, I have:
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
        <artifactId>openapi-generator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

Controller that is generated:
import jakarta.validation.constraints.*;
import jakarta.validation.Valid; //here it is ok

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;
import javax.annotation.Generated; //this is a problem

@Generated(value = "org.openapitools.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen", comments = "Generator version: 7.4.0") 
@Controller
@RequestMapping("${openapi.com.base-path:/rest/sample/v1}")
public class TestApiController implements TesterApi {

    private final TestApiDelegate delegate;

    public TestApiController(@Autowired(required = false) TestApiDelegate delegate) {
        this.delegate = Optional.ofNullable(delegate).orElse(new TestApiDelegate() {});
    }

    @Override
    public TestApiDelegate getDelegate() {
        return delegate;
    }

}


Why is it a problem? That annotation still exists, not everything moved to the jakarta namespace.

So just to add dependency for javax in that case? I thought that everything needs to be jakarta

Your thoughs are wrong. Only the JavaEE parts that moved to the Eclipse foundation are in the Jakarta package. This annotation is just basic and not part of JavaEE so just remains as is.

any recommendation where I can read up on those  namespaces what is where etc, so I know what I'm doing.. Btw, I added jakarta.annotation::jakarta.annotation-api and it is ok now
